# Silveright - [Parser_SetValue_NoSetter]

Tags: silverlight

I have a SL application that runs fine on some systems but encounters this error on others:

[image: Silverlight exception]

It's a really strange issue, there can be two machines in the same household, one will run one will output this error, both have the correct SL version installed and the success or failure is consistent across all browsers.

The full exception:

> [Parser_SetValue_NoSetter]
>   Arguments: 
>   Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.1.10329.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=Parser_SetValue_NoSetter
>
> at MS.Internal.XamlMemberInfo.SetValue(Object target, Object value)
>      at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.SetValue(XamlTypeToken inType, XamlQualifiedObject& inObj, XamlPropertyToken inProperty, XamlQualifiedObject& inValue)

I've deployed it from a local machine and to Azure - it makes no difference

www.theweatherproject.net

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and my solution was to install the latest silverlight version on the problematic systems. I know you did but...